# Problem with sending array via Soap WSDL - PHP

Tags: php

I have problem with send SOAP query. For some reason my code [numerNadania] isn't good. I guess it's some problem with structure.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:e=http://e-nadawca.poczta-polska.pl 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <e:addReklamacje>
            <reklamowanaPrzesylka 
            dataNadania="2018-05-22" 
            urzadNadania="260578" 
            powodReklamacjiOpis="TEST TEST TEST" 
odszkodowanie="0" oplata="0" oczekiwaneOdszkodowanie="0">
                <przesylka 
                    guid="262A34BA2C1111116237B659B312F5EB" 
                    numerNadania="00159007738099827991"
                    opis="TEST" 
                    planowanaDataNadania="2018-05-22"
                    xsi:type="e:przesylkaBiznesowaType"/>
            <powodReklamacji 
idPowodGlowny="4" 
powodGlownyOpis="TEST TEST TEST">
                    <powodSzczegolowy 
idPowodSzczegolowy="9" powodSzczegolowyOpis="TEST TEST TEST"/>
            </powodReklamacji>
            </reklamowanaPrzesylka>
        </e:addReklamacje>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapev:Envelope>
```

```
    $options["login"] = "***";
    $options["password"] = "***";
    $options["soap_version"] = SOAP_1_2;

    $wsdl = 'en.wsdl';

    try {
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
    }

    catch(Throwable $e) {
        echo 'Wystąpił problem z połączniem API';
    }

    $params = array(
        'reklamowanaPrzesylka' => array (
            'przesylka' => array (
                'guid' => getGuid(),
                'numerNadania' => $id,
            ),
            'powodReklamacji' => "Czas dostawy",
        )
    );

    $problem = $client->addReklamacje($params);
```

```
stdClass Object ( [errorNumber] => 13250 [errorDesc] => Numer nadania dla składanych reklamacji jest wymagany [guid] => F8CF816CDF4DD8151116C0EE340C4031 )
```

Numer nadania dla składanych reklamacji jest wymagany - Send number is required [TRANSLATE]

Answer (score 0):

In the past i have been using wsdl2php converters to create client code that resolves most of this type of issues.

See this one for example: https://github.com/rquadling/wsdl2php

They all work pretty much the same, you need to provide ?wsdl endpoint, run script and it will produce client code and output it in to file. Than you can include file and use generated classes and methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you think the reason is "xsi:type="e:przesylkaBiznesowaType"?

Comment: Do you know how to make it via SoapVar?